# spring boot enable redis http session

Tags: spring, redis, spring-session

I'm trying to use spring boots redis to store the sessions in it. When I follow their documentation, I always get an Exception when launching the server.

What I've done so far:
- I followed the documentation ([click](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot.html)) added the needed dependency and created the pretty small config class => then I launched the server and I always get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at demo.Application.main(Application.java:19)
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:140)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:229)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:57)
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration$EnableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:42)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:84)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:10)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:133)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:150)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:71)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1783)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:65)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:836)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:434)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:361)
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:40)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:144)
    ... 30 common frames omitted

2015-03-05 16:00:57.266  INFO 6580 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2015-03-05 16:00:57.266  INFO 6580 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Users/Patrick/workspace/examples/spring-boot/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.8/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.8.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.8/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.8.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.8/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.8.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.2/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.2/logback-core-1.1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.14/snakeyaml-1.14.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.15/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.15/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.15.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.15/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.15.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.15/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.15.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.4.4/jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.4.4/jackson-annotations-2.4.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.4.4/jackson-core-2.4.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.1.3.Final/hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.0.0/classmate-1.0.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4/2.1.4.RELEASE/thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/2.1.4.RELEASE/thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/ognl/ognl/3.0.8/ognl-3.0.8.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/unbescape/unbescape/1.1.0.RELEASE/unbescape-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.8/slf4j-api-1.7.8.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/nz/net/ultraq/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/1.2.7/thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.2.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-security-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-security-config-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/springframework/session/spring-session-data-redis/1.0.0.RELEASE/spring-session-data-redis-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-pool2/2.2/commons-pool2-2.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-redis/1.4.1.RELEASE/spring-data-redis-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context-support/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-context-support-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/org/springframework/session/spring-session/1.0.0.RELEASE/spring-session-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Patrick/.m2/repository/redis/clients/jedis/2.5.2/jedis-2.5.2.jar]
2015-03-05 16:00:57.266  INFO 6580 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enabled debug logging (start with --debug)


2015-03-05 16:00:57.266 ERROR 6580 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at demo.Application.main(Application.java:19)
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:140)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:229)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:57)
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration$EnableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:42)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:84)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:10)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:133)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:150)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:71)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1783)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:65)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:836)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:434)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:361)
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:40)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:144)
    ... 30 common frames omitted

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at demo.Application.main(Application.java:19)
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:140)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:229)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:57)
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration$EnableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:42)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:84)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:10)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:133)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:150)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:71)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1783)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:65)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:836)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:434)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:361)
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:40)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:144)
    ... 30 more
```

Because I couldn't find the error, I've imported their sample projects using gradle/maven and tested it, I'll get more or less the same exception...

Does somebody know that problem?

Comment: Instead of editing your post with the solution, post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception says that the application couldn't connect to the redis instance.
Do you have a redis server running somewhere?

1. Check your connection parameters in your configuration, that should solve the problem.
2. Make sure the redis server is reachable by using the redis CLI `./redis-cli -h yourhost -p 6379 -a passwordIfNecessary`

Note that the current [spring-data-redis (one of the projects backing spring-session) requires redis 2.6+](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#requirements).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was able to fix that problem by updating my redis server from version 2.4 to 2.8 (I've seen somewhere that spring doesn't support it below 2.8)

Comment: spring-data-redis requires 2.6+